# Change order status when order has backorder items in it

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

In WooCommerce, How to change the `on-hold` order status to something else, if this order has back-ordered items in it?

I have tried to use a custom function hooked in `woocommerce_order_status_on-hold` action hook without success.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function mysite_hold($order_id) {

    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $backorder = FALSE;

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item['Backordered']) {
            $backorder = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($backorder){
        $order->update_status('completed'); //change your status here
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'mysite_hold');

//You may need to store your backorder info like below

wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'Backordered', $qty - max(0, $product->get_total_stock()));
```

Please try this snippet

Comment: Thanks Working Perfectly
But This line shows an error:
wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id, 'Backordered', $qty - max(0, $product->get_total_stock()));

Comment: How to get order details in woocommerce?
If order contain sale price then i want to change the order status

Answer (score 6):

Here is a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_thankyou`** action hook, that will change the order status **if this order has a status "on-hold"** and **if it has any backorder products in it**.

You will have **to set** in the function **the desired new status slug** change.

Here is that custom function *(code is well commented)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'change_paid_backorders_status', 10, 1 );
function change_paid_backorders_status( $order_id ) {

    if ( ! $order_id )
        return;

    // HERE below set your new status SLUG for paid back orders  
    $new_status = 'completed';

    // Get a an instance of order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // ONLY for "on-hold" ORDERS Status
    if ( ! $order->has_status('on-hold') )
        return;

    // Iterating through each item in the order
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {

        // Get a an instance of product object related to the order item
        $product = $item->get_product();

        // Check if the product is on backorder
        if( $product->is_on_backorder() ){
            // Change this order status
            $order->update_status($new_status);
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code is tested and works.

Comment: Where the `$cart_item` variable coming from?

Comment: @RizwanKhan Sorry a typo error from an update… I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

edit code error on // Get a an instance of product object related to the order item

```
$product = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ? wc_get_product($item['product_id']) : $item->get_product();
```

Comment: Would you care to add any explanation, how this answer is related to the question?