# Check all orders with order status "Processing", and verify if their items are In Stock - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, orders

For a Woocommerce store that allows backorders (customers can purchase items that currently have no stock), with time as physical and store stocks are updated, there is no way to finally tell when an older order eventually has all the missing components (the products that were backordered, and that are now in stock) and is finally ready to be packed.

Due to this:
The objective is to frequently check/query/loop through all orders with order status "Processing" and check what is the current status of each of their items and if all items are in stock (So there are no items that have current stock status on backorder), then it will update this order with a custom ACF field 'Ready to Pack'

This attempt is initially based on [Auto completed status for all existing processing orders in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037932/auto-completed-status-for-all-existing-processing-orders-in-woocommerce/41038073#41038073) and also has a bit of [Change order status when order has backorder items in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577974/change-order-status-when-order-has-backorder-items-in-it)

```
    function auto_update_orders_internal_status(){
         
                 // Get all current "processing" customer orders
            $processing_orders = wc_get_orders( $args = array(
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'post_status' => 'wc-processing',
            ) );
            if(!empty($processing_orders))
                foreach($processing_orders as $order) {
                    
         // Iterating through each item in the order
            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        
                // Get a an instance of product object related to the order item
                $product = $item->get_product();
        
                // Check if the products are currently in stock 
                if( $product->is_in_stock() ){
    
                    // Update custom field 'Ready to Pack'
               add_action('acf/save_post', 'update_internal_status_ready_to_pack');
            }}
            }
        }         
        

  //Run check function when an order status is change to completed
  add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'auto_update_orders_internal_status' );
    

  //Save ACF field function
  function update_internal_status_ready_to_pack ( $order_id ) {
            
            $internalstatus = 'Ready to Pack';
            update_field( 'internal_status', $internalstatus, $order_id );
        
        }
```

One thing I am aware I don't fully grasp here is the method of , after getting all orders on "Processing status", successfully checking each order the stock status of their corresponding items

Comment: Not really clear what you are trying to ask here. You can see how the stock status gets checked right there in the code, so … what exactly is unclear?

Comment: One thing is that this approach may mean some orders never get fully satisfied.  As other orders may become complete and take stock which is needed to complete another order it becomes a never ending cycle of 1 item missing stops an order going out.

Comment: @NigelRen This is a very good point for a global application but actually not a relevant complication for us because when new stock arrives, it is always enough to fulfill all previous requests. 
Besides this, orders are fulfilled by age and once an order would get it's custom field updated to "Ready to pack" it would not be altered again
Of course it would be great if this would be contemplated, but I'm just trying to get the basic to work

Comment: @CBroe  the code is my approach but unfortunately it is not working, I do not fully grasp PHP enough yet to figure out and I am not sure if the approach I am taking is the best practice for this particular application